# Adding string to data frame cells in R

Tags: r, string

I'm fairly new to R and want to know how to add a string to cell values in 1 column.  For example I have an excel sheet that I will import as a data frame in R that looks like this:

[image]

I want to add "_L" to every odd number cell in the subject column, and "_R" to every even number cell in the subject column to get something like this:

[image]

How would I do that?  And FYI, this is just a snippet of my data, there are hundreds of rows which is why I'd like an automatic way to do it in R.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You may do `df1$Subject <- paste0(df1$Subject, "_", c("L", "R"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### base R

```r
dat <- data.frame(subj = rep(1:3, each=2), mean=11:16)
ltrs <- ave(dat$subj, dat$subj, FUN = function(z) ifelse(seq_along(z) %% 2 == 0, "R", "L"))
ltrs
# [1] "L" "R" "L" "R" "L" "R"
dat$subj <- paste0(dat$subj, "_", ltrs)
dat
#   subj mean
# 1  1_L   11
# 2  1_R   12
# 3  2_L   13
# 4  2_R   14
# 5  3_L   15
# 6  3_R   16
```

This properly handles if there are other than "2" of each `subj`, and it always assigns `"L"` to the odd rows within each `subj`.

### tidyverse

If you're already using `dplyr` for things, then you can use this.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(subj) %>%
  mutate(subj = paste0(subj, "_", if_else(row_number() %% 2 == 0, "R", "L"))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   subj   mean
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 1_L      11
# 2 1_R      12
# 3 2_L      13
# 4 2_R      14
# 5 3_L      15
# 6 3_R      16
```

Comment: Thank you @r2evans!  Ended up using the dplyr option and that worked perfectly.